# Contact attached to every node of a particular type

Tags: forms, webforms

I am trying to figure out how to attach one form to every node of a particular content type in Drupal.

Each node will be owned by a different user and the form will be sent to the user who created that node.

The closest I have got is with Webform and Webform Templates. However, It makes the user choose the template to use. I don't want that I want it to be set automatically and I can't see how it can be?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: which version are you using Drupal6 or Drupal7?

Comment: @Bala I'm using D7 and Webform 7.x-4.0-beta1

Comment: You are looking for https://drupal.org/project/authorcontact but this is for Drupal 6.

Comment: you can check this module https://drupal.org/project/node_feedback

Comment: I think i'll need to write my own form module for this use case. Webform almost does exactly what I need. If I could just make it use a predefined template instead of giving the user the choice. I'll take another look to see if it allows me to do that, if not, custom module it is.

Comment: Doesn't this settings page - admin/config/content/webform_template/defaults - provide an option to set the default webform template for each content type?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing [Form Block](https://drupal.org/project/formblock) module which give you possibility to expose a form as a block. And you can configure appearance of that block on every node of a particular content type.

> To enable adding of a form to a node, select the option "Enable data
>   entry from a block" in the admin configuration page for a given
>   content type. Visit the block administration page and enable/configure
>   the block for the form.